# Monospace Unicode font

Tags: unicode, fonts

Can anybody please tell me the monospace font that covers most of the unicode characters If not then a monospace font that contains most of the european language character set ?

Comment: `Noto Sans Mono`,  https://www.google.com/get/noto/#sans-mono , I changed my TeXStudio editor font to that, it has the variety unicode chars I use.

Answer (score 26):

I'm also searching for mono space, rich Unicode font. So far I use DejaVu Sans Mono, but I wanted to know whether there is better (for me) replacement.

So, as of today, I have downloaded the following TTF fonts and count their number of glyphs:

- [DejaVu Sans Mono](https://dejavu-fonts.github.io/): 3289
- [Everson Mono](http://evertype.com/emono/): 9671
- [Fixedsys Excelsior](http://www.fixedsysexcelsior.com/): 5993
- [FreeMono](http://www.gnu.org/software/freefont/): 4177
- [GNU Unifont](http://www.unifoundry.com/unifont.html): 57089
- [Lucida Sans Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucida_Sans_Unicode): 1779

But their usefulness is also matter of what symbols are exactly supported and how they look. For example the Fixedsys and Unifont have old-school appearance. Anyway, this could be useful info for somebody...

Comment: Lucida Sans Unicode isn't monospaced: The very first word in the question headline.

Answer (score 19):

Nearly every font nowadays covers at least Latin, Greek and Cyrillic. And enough of Latin to support most European languages.

However, there can't be a single font covering most of Unicode, as OpenType is limited to 65536 glyphs and there are more code points assigned so far. Also it's a common misconception that a single font for as many scripts as possible is a Good Thing™. It's not, actually. Remember that for the font to work other things must be in place as well: properly defined diacritics support (so combining accents actually appear *above/below* the base characters and not somewhere next to them), precomposed glyphs for some scripts so the rendering engine can use them properly, this includes Arabic and and Indic scripts, ...

It's a major undertaking and as such it's not surprising that pretty much the only fonts covering large portions of Unicode are *last-resort* fonts, intended to be used when no other font exists to display something. As a fallback mechanism, but never as a first choice. The preferred way is actually to let the rendering engine sort out script support for fonts and not try to cram it all into a single font. See also Michael Kaplan's take on this: [Arial Unicode MS effectively [bites|sucks|blows]](http://www.siao2.com/2007/07/15/3890144.aspx) .

Still, if you're only looking for glyph support:

- Fixedsys Excelsior
- Everson Mono
- DejaVu Sans Mono
- Roboto Mono

Those fonts are pretty large already. But as noted above, don't count on correct workings of complex scripts or typography.

Comment: Use Case: If you are working with xelatex or lualatex with large multilingual documents and you'd like to read the logs, then you're probably going to need a typeface that can cover many glyphs such that you can properly identify missing characters in the logs e.g. "Missing character: There is no (character) in font [...]" (if character does not exist, you just see a square box).

Comment: @macmadness86: Restrictions of the Windows console notwithstanding, font substitution is a thing and works and it's the proper solution here. As noted there is a *technical* reason why this cannot be done, so finding use cases to advocate for something that cannot be done is a futile effort, I think. Also, I'd hope XeLaTeX gives you error messages that unambiguously mark the error by line/column number.

Comment: I was merely adding a use case where having many glyphs is important--like 65536 of them. In situations where >65536 glyphs are needed, substitution is supported by xelatex using `\XeTeXcharclass` and `\XeTeXinterchartoks`. Unfortunately, error messages regarding missing characters are often ambiguous :(

Comment: Isn't it __Roboto__ Mono?

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake: Sure; you can also edit the answer directly, which is perhaps easier :-)

Comment: A limitation of font substitution: It messes up column alignment. I'm running into this issue with emacs and `prettify-symbols-mode'.

Comment: Well, you'd need monospace fonts with the same metrics for that to work, although I think that applications that require an actual character grid, such as a console, should take care of positioning glyphs themselves.

Comment: Lucida Sans Unicode isn't monospaced: The very first word in the question headline.

Answer (score 16):

**Osaka Mono** 
(If you are crazy like me and want to program with Japanese variable names.)
[image: Osaka Mono At 24PT]

**Full Name:** Osaka-等幅

**CSS:** font-family:'Osaka-Mono';

After looking at 25+ fonts, I only found
1 that fit all of my criteria for programming:

```
Chart Key:
==============================================
FWK : Full Width Kanji
FWR : Full Width Roman Characters
HWA : Half Width Ascii Characters
oO0 : Can differentiate o vs O vs 0 ?
il1 : Can differentiate i vs l vs 1 ?
ZOM : Does NOT mis-align when zooming?
==============================================
                FWK  FWR  HWA  oO0  il1  ZOM 
*Osaka Mono   :  Y    Y    Y    Y    Y    Y
GNU Unifont   :  Y    Y    Y    Y    Y    -
*NotoSansMCJR :  Y    Y    Y    -    Y    -
*MS Gothic    :  Y    Y    Y    -    *    Y
Kochi Gothic  :  Y    Y    Y    -    -    Y
Hanazono Micho:  Y    Y    Y    -    -    Y
MS Hei        :  Y    Y    Y    -    -    Y
**IPA Gothic  :  Y    Y    Y    Y    Y    Y

*NotoSansMCJR : Full name is "Noto Sans Mono CJK JP Regular"
*MS Gothic    : il1 difference is subtle.
*Osaka Mono   : 
                CSS: font-family:'Osaka-Mono';
                In text editor drop down, will
                likely be: "Osaka-等幅"

**IPA Gothic  : The "\" symbol displays as a
                yen sign in HTML pages and
                my text editor. Deal breaker.
```

Fonts I found **unsuable** because either:

1. Kanji were not exactly 2 ascii chars wide.
2. Full width unicode letters were not exactly 2 ascii chars wide.

==============================================

1. Andale Mono
2. Apple Gothic
3. Bitstream Cyberbit
4. Consolas
5. DejaVu Sans Mono
6. Everson Mono
7. FixedSys Excelsior
8. Free Mono
9. Han Wang Hei Heavy
10. Han Wang Min Black
11. Han Wang Zon Yi
12. Kaiso Next B
13. Kozuka Gothic Pro R
14. Lucidia Sans Unicode
15. Monospace (By George William )
16. Nanum Gothic
17. Noto Mono
18. Noto Mono Regular
19. Noto Sans CJK JP Regular
20. Osaka
21. Roboto
22. Roboto Mono
23. Un Yetgul

==============================================

Comment: Fantastic comparison, upvoted. Any idea where to obtain Osaka-Mono?

Comment: Searching for "Osaka - 等幅" where "等幅" is Japanese for "Monospaced" will help. Google translate will be your friend, because I found it on a Japanese website. I don't read Japanese. I just like Kanji and can recognize more symbols than most non readers.

Answer (score 11):

There's the [GNU Unifont](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Unifont) project, which more or less has this as its goal.

Comment: GNU Unifont is a coarse bitmap font, which is suitable for simulating early display devices and matrix printers from the 1960s.

Comment: there is also a vectorized ttf version now

Comment: This is the best answer today I think.

Comment: Probably worth noting that the "vectorized" version just converts each pixel to a square, so it still looks pixelated when you scale it.

Answer (score 10):

For those of you who were in need of an overview to make sense of many good suggestions here and elsewhere: here is something I made.

I downloaded 39 monospaced fonts I found on the internet and used [Fontkit](https://github.com/foliojs/fontkit) to get the number of supported Unicode points. I manually added the supported styles. I hope this helps!

| Font | #Supported Unicode Points | Styles |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GNU Unifont<sup>1</sup> | 57087 | Regular |
| Nanum Gothic Coding<sup>2</sup> | 12478 | Bold, Regular |
| JuliaMono | 9800 | Regular |
| Everson Mono<sup>3</sup> | 9643 | Bold, BoldOblique, Oblique, Regular |
| GNU Freefont | 4160 | Bold, BoldOblique, Oblique, Regular |
| Noto Sans Mono<sup>4</sup> | 3367 | Black, Bold, ExtraBold, ExtraLight, Light, Medium, Regular, SemiBold, Thin |
| DejaVu Sans Mono | 3258 | Bold, BoldOblique, Oblique, Regular |
| Monospace | 2881 | Bold, Oblique, Regular |
| Cousine | 2275 | Bold, BoldItalic, Italic, Regular |
| Overpass Mono | 1642 | Bold, Light, Medium, Regular, SemiBold |
| Fira Code | 1586 | Bold, Light, Medium, Regular, Retina, SemiBold |
| Hack | 1549 | Bold, BoldItalic, Italic, Regular |
| Fira Mono | 1350 | Bold, Medium, Regular |
| Source Code Pro | 1334 | Black, BlackItalic, Bold, BoldItalic, ExtraBold, ExtraBoldItalic, ExtraLight, ExtraLightItalic, Italic, Light, LightItalic, Medium, MediumItalic, Regular, SemiBold, SemiBoldItaliic |
| Nova Mono | 1329 | Regular |
| Ubuntu Mono | 1225 | Bold, BoldItalic, Italic, Regular |
| Jetbrains mono | 1182 | Bold, BoldItalic, ExtraBold, ExtraBoldItalic, ExtraLight, ExtraLightItalic, Italic, Light, LightItalic, Medium, MediumItalic, Regular, SemiBold, SemiBoldItaliic, Thin, ThinItalic |
| Input | 923 | Black, BlackItalic, Bold, BoldItalic, ExtraLight, ExtraLightItalic, Italic, Light, LightItalic, Medium, MediumItalic, Regular, Thin, ThinItalic |
| Inconsolata | 883 | Regular |
| Roboto Mono | 877 | Bold, BoldItalic, ExtraLight, ExtraLightItalic, Italic, Light, LightItalic, Medium, MediumItalic, Regular, SemiBold, SemiBoldItaliic, Thin, ThinItalic |
| Droid Sans Mono | 872 | Regular |
| PT Mono | 806 | Regular |
| IBM Plex Mono | 751 | BlackItalic, Bold, BoldItalic, ExtraLight, ExtraLightItalic, Italic, Light, LightItalic, Medium, MediumItalic, Regular, SemiBold, SemiBoldItaliic, Thin, ThinItalic |
| Anonyous Pro | 624 | Bold, BoldItalic, Italic, Regular |
| Monoid | 619 | Bold, Italic, Regular, Retina |
| Space Mono | 614 | Bold, BoldItalic, Italic, Regular |
| B612 Mono | 590 | Bold, BoldItalic, Italic, Regular |
| Major Mono Display | 582 | Regular |
| VT323 | 569 | Regular |
| Xanh Mono | 468 | Italic, Regular |
| Cutive Mono | 440 | Regular |
| Azeret Mono | 434 | Black, BlackItalic, Bold, BoldItalic, ExtraBold, ExtraBoldItalic, ExtraLight, ExtraLightItalic, Italic, Light, LightItalic, Medium, MediumItalic, Regular, SemiBold, SemiBoldItaliic, Thin, ThinItalic |
| Spline Sans Mono | 412 | Bold, BoldItalic, Italic, Light, LightItalic, Medium, MediumItalic, Regular, SemiBold, SemiBoldItalic |
| Red Hat Mono | 393 | Bold, BoldItalic, Italic, Light, LightItalic, Medium, MediumItalic, Regular, SemiBold, SemiBoldItaliic |
| Courier Prime | 384 | Bold, BoldItalic, Italic, Regular |
| DM Mono | 382 | Italic, Light, LightItalic, Medium, MediumItalic, Regular |
| Syne Mono | 380 | Regular |
| Oxygen Mono | 360 | Regular |
| Share Tech Mono | 268 | Regular |

---

<sup>1</sup>Although the Unicode support is superior, the font itself is quite 'blocky' because of its BMP origin.
<sup>2</sup>The Unicode support might seem high, but this is mostly due to the support of the Korean language.
<sup>3</sup>This font doesn't seem to handle the non-breaking spaces differently.
<sup>4</sup>Some characters use a double amount (basically 2 'normal' characters) of width.

Answer (score 1):

The Unicode font *called* Monospace will cover pretty much all European characters, but lacks the Asian ones.

Answer (score 1):

Consolas is a modern monospace font shipped with Micosoft's products.

An example of a font that covers a wide range of Unicode characters is Arial Unicode shipped with Microsoft Office products.

Comment: (a) It's Arial Unicode MS. (b) It's not monospaced. (c) It's a last-resort font, not one that should be specified to use: http://blogs.msdn.com/michkap/archive/2007/07/15/3890144.aspx

Comment: @Joey and (d) that link is broken :)

Comment: @Clément: I think it was [this one](http://www.siao2.com/2007/07/15/3890144.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

While the technical specifications exist that would permit to create huge fonts, potentially covering the whole unicode range, in practice:
 – many apps and software stacks do not support all those opentype extensions (typically locl and OTC: https://blogs.adobe.com/CCJKType/2014/09/shs-otf-or-otc.html )
 – designing all the required glyphs, and their composition rules, is a *huge* undertaking, many man-years to do it right

So such fonts do not exist now, or trade coverage for quality

Therefore international software should not posit the existence of a pan-unicode font but be able to compose as many different fonts as needed, with different and often overlapping coverage. It makes the software developer work harder as one may not assume the same font file is used for consecutive glyphs.

This is how modern text stacks work (for example harfbuzz-ng + fontconfig…)

Answer (score 0):

The ONLY standard install font I have ever found that works with a good range of unicode blocks encoded is...

```
FONT="-misc-fixed-medium-r-*-*-15-*-75-75-c-90-iso10646-1"
BFONT="-misc-fixed-bold-r-*-*-15-*-75-75-c-90-iso10646-1"
```

I set Xresources to...

```
XtDefaultFont:  -misc-fixed-bold-r-*-*-15-*-75-75-c-90-iso10646-1
XTerm*font:     -misc-fixed-medium-r-*-*-15-*-75-75-c-90-iso10646-1
XTerm*boldFont: -misc-fixed-bold-r-*-*-15-*-75-75-c-90-iso10646-1
```

This Font includes Glyphs for...

```
Arrows U+2190
Mathematical U+2200
Technical U+2300
Miscellaneous U+2400
Graphics U+2500
Miscellaneous Symbols U+2600
Dingbats U+2700
Braile U+2800
```

I have tried to use the newer, GTK and Truetype unicode fonts.  And while they implement a larger range of glyphs, including he latest emoji.  But they mostly suffer when you simply want a fixed-width font that really is FIXED-WIDTH!

The Graphics and Mathematical Blocks for example often do not work with character extensions across multiple lines. You often only have to look at Extended Braces, to see the font and application falling flat on its face, with symbol characters not lining up properly.

Add to that the applications often leave gaps between characters or between lines, making characters 'fuzzy' from over use of scaling and anti-aliasing in the rendering, or not implementing the combining properities for the unicode block "`Combining Diacritical Marks for Symbols U+20D0 - U+20FF`" and you see the newer fonts are basically a sorry mess!

Basically XTerms, and X-Window "fixed" font (as above) seemed to have put in the time and thought put into making the font work properly as a whole.

Big thanks to Markus Kuhn for such a great effort!

For my notes from researching this see...
http://www.ict.griffith.edu.au/anthony/info/data/utf8-demo.txt

Answer (score 0):

`Noto Sans Mono`,  https://www.google.com/get/noto/#sans-mono , I changed my TeXStudio editor font to that, it has the variety unicode chars I use.