# How to set character width in html/css

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a font with all characters the same width in html div.

For example, a W is wider than an i in most fonts ...Is there any font that has all characters equally wide?

Comment: You mean a [monospaced font](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font)? There are lots, such as Consolas.

Comment: Or maybe you're looking for `<pre>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a monospace font...

Here are some examples: https://fonts.google.com/?category=Monospace

Answer (score 2):

You could to separate the character with an individual class and then you can use `transform: scale(x, y);` to alter the characters width and height.

```css
.text {
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    text-transform: full-width;
    -webkit-transform:scale(15.0,1.0);
    -moz-transform:scale(15.0, 1.0);
    -ms-transform:scale(15.0, 1.0);
    -o-transform:scale(15.0, 1.0);
    transform:scale(15.0,1.0);
}
```

```html
<div class="text">tc</div>
```

Comment: `letter-spacing` is the same thing I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

**What you are looking for is a [monospace font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font), i.e. a font with fixed-width characters.**

Now, to use such a font you could either [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@import) one and use it directly by its name, like so:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono');
div { font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace; }
```

```html
<div><p>Some text in a div</p></div>
```

Or you could simply rely on the [`monospace` value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/font-family) itself, which means that the user will see a font based on the browser and OS they are using:

```css
div { font-family: monospace; }
```

```html
<div><p>Some text in a div</p></div>
```

Alternatively, you could use the [`pre` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) instead of a div, as it typically displays text in a monospace font anyway:

```html
<pre>Some text in a pre.</pre>
```

To find some fixed-width fonts, you can use [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/?classification=Monospace), they have a filter just for that. Also, there are other questions/answers on the Stack Exchange network that are related and might be of use to you, for example:

- [What is a monospace font in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9962994/what-is-a-monospace-font-in-ios)
- [What is the GNOME Classic Monospace font?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154736/what-is-the-gnome-classic-monospace-font)
- [Some pretty fixed width font for Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/191691/some-pretty-fixed-width-font-for-windows)
- [Monospace Unicode font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938639/monospace-unicode-font)