# Pandoc/PowerShell option to use to avoid ​�? in place of the closing double quotes

Tags: windows, powershell, markdown, pandoc

I use the following Powershell script to convert the raw Markdown-Plain-Text in my clipboard into **pastable** things that can be used in an arbitrary browser. I use it most heavily for writing emails in Gmail, and for Google Docs.

```
paste.exe | pandoc -f markdown -t HTML |  Set-Clipboard -AsHtml ; echo 'Conversion done.'
```

It has been working amazingly well, except for its conversion of the closing double quotes.

- When I type, I do not distinguish between the Opening and the Closing quotation marks;
- Either, it is `pandoc` that wanted to help, but screw up a bit,
- Or, it is the `Set-Clipboard` Powershell command that needs a bit more of attention.

Experts, please advise what "magic flag" to put, so that I can avoid manually cleaning up the `�?` markers all over the place.

Comment: `$(paste.exe)  -replace '“','"'  -replace '”','"'` _should_ translate all _Left_ and _Right_ Double Quotation Marks (`U+201C` and `U+201D`, respectively) to common ones `U+0022` (Unicode standard does not know terms _Opening_ and _Closing_ for quotation marks).

Comment: Note that `[console]::OutputEncoding` determines how PowerShell interprets  the output from `paste.exe` and `pandoc` and, on sending `paste.exe` output to `pandoc`, PowerShell uses the encoding specified in preference variable `$OutputEncoding`, which, unfortunately, defaults to _ASCII_ in Windows Powershell; see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49481797/45375

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [disable](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extensions) Pandoc's [smart](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-smart) extension, which is enabled by default for `markdown`, `latex`, and `context` output.

```
pandoc -f markdown-smart -t HTML
```

Note that you "disable" an extension by appending `-EXTENSION` to the format, where `EXTENSION` is the extension name. Therefore the format is `markdown-smart`. Conversely you can enable an extension with `+EXTENSION`. So you might read `markdown-smart` as "markdown minus smart".

As an aside, the name `smart` is likely borrowed from [SmartyPants](https://daringfireball.net/projects/smartypants/), a postprocessor to the original Markdown implementation which replaces straight quotes with curly quotes among other things. I found the extension by opening the Pandoc User Guide and searching for `smart`. Now you know. ;-)

Comment: Great. For some reason, when I pass things through Powershell, it did not like `markdown-smart` as a whole. Instead, adding a space in between does the job like magic! The command that worked for me is: ` pandoc -f markdown -smart -t HTML `. [@Waylan, would you mind updating your post? It won't let me insert one extra character when editing on my side.]

Comment: no idea what powershell is doing, but the proper command is without the space.

Comment: I'm not going to update my answer as that would make it wrong for most people.

Comment: Confirm that nor does Powershell liked the space. My current setup uses exactly the same flags as you prescribed. Not sure why I needed a whitespace when I first tested the flags.

Comment: Update for the `markdown -smart` vs `markdown-smart`. The former is expected when I install Pandoc through `chocolatey` on a Windows 10 machine, through Admin-righted-PowerShell. Source: https://chocolatey.org/packages/pandoc

Comment: The error message it threw at me was: `pandoc.exe: Unknown extension: smart`. I happen to be running the conversion script through AutoHotKey, and I am not that interested to fix a pandoc flg issue ==> ended up adding conditional statements based on the machine-name to feed in the _locally correct_ set of flags.