# Set and Output Variables with Non-ASCII Values

Tags: powershell

My variables are not properly displaying if they contain non-ASCII characters:

```
$Test = '♭'
$Test
```

Expected output: `♭` Actual output: `â™­`

In an old batch script I could fix it by running this command at the top of my script: `chcp 65001` However, it doesn't work in PowerShell and I can't find anything like it.

How can I properly set non-ASCII values for my variables?

My .ps1 file is UTF-8 encoded, so the problem isn't there.

Comment: If you have the unicode encoding you can write `[char]0xcode`.

Comment: It worked as expected for me on PS 5.1 ISE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying Unicode in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49476326/displaying-unicode-in-powershell)

Comment: @RohinSidharth it worked in ISE for me too, but not when I run the .ps1 script.

Comment: @Moerwald that page deals with font issues. That's not my issue. I also tried what they suggested but it did not resolve my issue.

Comment: Try out some of the answers here (even the ones at the bottom, there are a few varieties). https://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8

Comment: This answer looks promising: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49476326/displaying-unicode-in-powershell

Comment: So the question is, "how do I display unicode characters in the powershell console"?

Comment: It works in the ise or osx, like in my deleted answer.  But I can't get it to work in the console in windows so far, despite all these links.

Answer (score 0):

I've confirmed that these fonts display the "flat sign" ok in the console, with no other changes:  MS Gothic, NSimSun, SimSum-ExtB.  Although the blackslash looks strange in MS Gothic.

Strange how Consolas and Lucida Console work ok in the ISE.

It works in the VSCode console too by the way, even though $outputencoding is set to ascii.

I tried this to mimic the ISE, but it says unknown type.

```
$OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.SBCSCodePageEncoding
```