# Text Encoding between Linux and Windows

Tags: linux, powershell, encoding, decoding

The main question I have is how can I get a textfile that I have in Linux to display properly in PowerShell.

In Linux, I have text files with some special characters, and in fact Notepad displays the text file exactly as it is displayed in Linux:

[image: Notepad output]

Unfortunately, my program prints to my Linux Terminal, and thus I need the same output in my Windows terminal. I have seen through other answers that

1. I need to use a TrueType font, so I am using Lucidia Console
2. on my Linux device, the encoding is UTF-8. According to every answer I can find online, CHCP 65001 switches the code page in PowerShell to UTF-8
3. Windows Powershell is better equipped to display content, so while I have tried using the command prompt, I am now working in PowerShell.

Using CHCP 65001 and then typing

```
more my_file.txt
```

displays this:

[image: result from more command]

while using

```
Get-Content -Encoding UTF8 my_file.txt
```

outputs:

[image: result from get-content]

Neither of these results is good enough, but I am actually concerned that Get-Content does something different at all here. The code that I am transferring to windows is written in Free Pascal, and in Free Pascal, I can provide a UTF-8 codepage, but that's it. So while Get-Content is a good command for me to check if PowerShell is capable of producing the desired output, it is not practical for me to use it. In Pascal, the output (which is written to the PowerShell display) appears as:

[image: Pascal Display]

Which is bad as well, those lines should connect because they do in Linux (and obviously some characters are interpreted just as ?). However, this might be a problem with the codepage picked in Pascal, which would be a next step.

My question right now is, how can I get the Windows Powershell to, by default, display a text file as it is shown in the notepad version. It is not practical for me to run Get-Content in my code everywhere, so although that result appears more promising, I cannot follow that.

As a follow up question, because I could not find it anywhere online, what are the main players here when it comes to displaying content, because it is clearly a bigger story than just the encoding. Why are the 'more' and the 'Get-Content' commands displaying different outputs? And why can 'Get-Content' not read all of the content? I had assumed UTF-8 was a universal standard, and programs who can read UTF-8 could at least actually read all of the characters, but they're all reading it differently.

The input, as text, is:

```
    ╭─────╮
    │     │
  ╭─│───╮ │
  │ │   │ │
  │ │ ╭─│───╮
  │ │ │ │ │ │
╭─│───│─╯ │ │
│ │ │ │   │ │
│ │ ╰─╯   │ │
│ │       │ │
│ ╰───────│─╯
│         │
╰─────────╯
```

In response to an answer posted below, I can see that

```
more my_file.txt
```

produces

[image: more command output using OutputEncoding]

when using

```
$OutputEncoding = [console]::InputEncoding = [console]::OutputEncoding = 
  New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding
```

Comment: @AdminOfThings that result is the same as the Get-Content output.

Comment: So I'm seeing `gc $file -Encoding UTF8` is getting the characters that were posted into your post. I'm also seeing the ReadAllText .net function posted by AdminOfThings has the same result. It appears to be getting the content correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **Make sure that your UTF-8-encoded text file *has a BOM*** - otherwise, your file will be misinterpreted by *Windows PowerShell* as being encoded based on the system's active ANSI code page (whereas PowerShell [Core] 6+ now thankfully consistently defaults to UTF-8 in the absence of a BOM).

  - Alternatively, use `Get-Content -Encoding Utf8 my_file.txt` to explicitly specify the file's encoding.
  - For a comprehensive discussion of character encoding in Windows PowerShell vs. PowerShell [Core], see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098904/45375).
- For **output from *external programs*** to be *correctly captured in a variable* or *correctly redirect to a file*, **you need to set `[Console]::OutputEncoding` to the character encoding that the given program uses** on output (for mere *printing to the display* this may not be necessary, however):

  - If code page `65001` (UTF-8) is in effect *and your program honors that*, you'll need to set `[Console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding`; see below for how to ensure that `65001` is truly in effect, given that running `chcp 65001` *from inside PowerShell* is *not* effective.
  - You mention FreePascal, whose Unicode support is described [here](https://wiki.freepascal.org/Unicode_Support_in_Lazarus).
    However, your screen shot implies that your FreePascal program's output is *not* UTF-8, because the rounded-corner characters were transcoded to `?` characters (which suggests a lossy transcoding to the system's OEM code page, where these characters aren't present).
  - Therefore, to solve your problem **you must ensure that your FreePascal program either *unconditionally* outputs UTF-8 or *honors the active code page*** (as reported by `chcp`), **assuming you've first set it to `65001`** (the UTF-8 code page; see below).
- **Choose a font that can render the rounded-corner Unicode characters** (such as `╭` ([`U+256D`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/256d)) in your console window; the Windows PowerShell default font, `Lucinda Console`, can *not* (it renders [image], as shown in your question), but `Consolas`, for instance (which PowerShell [Core] 6+ uses by default), *can*.

---

**Using UTF-8 encoding *with external programs* consistently**:

**Note**:

- The command below is neither necessary for nor does it have any effect on *PowerShell* commands such as the `Get-Content` cmdlet.
- Some **legacy console applications** - notably `more.com` (which Windows PowerShell wraps in a `more` *function*)  - **fundamentally do not support Unicode**, only the legacy OEM code pages.<sup>[*]</sup>

> According to every answer I can find online, CHCP 65001 switches the code page in PowerShell to UTF-8

**`chcp 65001` does *not* work if run from *within PowerShell***, because .NET *caches* the `[Console]::OutputEncoding` value at PowerShell session startup, with the code page that was in effect at that time.

Instead, you can use the following to fully make a console window UTF-8 aware (which implicitly also makes `chcp` report `65001` afterwards):

```
$OutputEncoding = [console]::InputEncoding = [console]::OutputEncoding =
                    New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding
```

This makes PowerShell interpret an external program's output as UTF-8, and also encodes data it sends *to* external program as UTF-8 (thanks to preference variable `$OutputEncoding`).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49481797/45375) for more information.

---

<sup>[*] With the UTF-8 code page `65001` in effect, `more` *quietly skips lines* that contain at least one Unicode character that cannot be mapped onto the system's OEM code page (any character not present in the system's single-byte OEM code page, which can only represent 256 characters), which in this case applies to the lines that contain the rounded-corner characters such as `╭` (BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT ARC DOWN AND RIGHT, [`U+256D`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/256d)).</sup>