# Use Haskell to Output Utf8 String in the PowerShell on Windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell, haskell, utf-8

Here is the code.

```hs
module Lib
    ( someFunc
    ) where

someFunc :: IO ()
someFunc = putStrLn "你好"
```

I tried to run the program in the PowerShell on Windows 10.

```
chcp 936
stack run
```

And the output is:

```
─π║├
```

Here is another try:

```
chcp 65001
stack run
```

And the output is:

```
Σ╜áσÑ╜
```

Any suggestion to make it work appropriately?

Comment: The latter is this kind of [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake):  `"你好".encode('utf-8').decode('cp437')` returns `'Σ╜áσÑ╜'` (example in Python as I don't speak Haskell, sorry.) And the former is analogous: `"你好".encode('cp936').decode('cp437')` returns `'─π║├'`. Check `[console]::OutputEncoding` in PowerShell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chcp` doesn't work from *inside* PowerShell, due to caching performed by .NET.

You can perform an equivalent command in PowerShell as follows, using the equivalent of
`chcp 65001` (changing to the UTF-8 code page) as an example:

```sh
[Console]::InputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = $OutputEncoding = 
  [System.Text.Utf8Encoding]::new()  # BOM-less UTF-8
```

To get other encodings, by their Windows code-page number (or name), use [`[System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60727989/45375) for background information.