# Powershell and Unicode support

Tags: powershell, unicode

I tested deno https://deno.land/ in Powershell

```
deno run https://deno.land/std/examples/welcome.ts
```

It outputs

```
Welcome to Deno ? ??
```

instead of

```
Welcome to Deno
```

Doesn't Powershell support Unicode ?

Comment: It works well in the ISE.

Comment: Hopefully, the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49481797/45375) answers your question.

Comment: it's the issue of the console (conhost.exe) and not the shell (powershell.exe). PowerShell fully supports Unicode

Comment: It also works fine in OS X in both Terminal and Vscode.  It half works in Windows Terminal.