# Bad Encoding when redirecting output of nodejs program to file (windows 10 powershell possible issue)

Tags: node.js, powershell, encoding

I have a simple javascript file (let's call it index.js) with the following:

```
console.log('pérola');
```

I use VSCode on windows 10 and it uses as terminal the powershell, when I execute the file using:

```
node index.js
```

I get the following output:

```
pérola
```

If I run the following:

```
node index.js > output.txt
```

I get the following on the file:

```
p├®rola
```

It seems there is some issue with the encoding of powershell when writing to files, when I open the file on VSCode I can see on the bottom right that the encoding is UTF-16 LE.

I also already tried the following:

```
node index.js | out-file -encoding utf8 output.txt
```

The file is saved in UTF8 with BOM but still with wrong encoding since what I see is **p├®rola** and not **pérola**

Can someone explain me what is wrong here?
Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What `node` outputs is UTF-8-encoded.

PowerShell's `>` operator does *not* pass the underlying bytes through to the output file. [*Update*: in [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) **v7.4+** it now *does*.]

Instead, PowerShell converts the bytes output by `node` into .NET strings *based on the encoding stored in `[Console]::OutputEncoding`* and then saves the resulting strings based on the encoding implied by the `>` operator, which is - effectively, not technically - an alias of the [`Out-File`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/) cmdlet.

In other words: for PowerShell to properly interpret `node`'s output you must (temporarily) set `[Console]::OutputEncoding` to `[System.Text.Utf8Encoding]::new()`.

Additionally, you must then decide what character encoding you want the output file to have, by using `Out-File -Encoding` or - preferably, if the input is *text* already - `Set-Content -Encoding` instead of `>`.
That is, you need to do this unless `>` / `Out-File`'s *default* character encoding works for you: it is "Unicode" (UTF16-LE) in *Windows PowerShell*, and BOM-less UTF-8 in *PowerShell [Core] v6+*.

See also:

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49481797/45375) for background information on how to make *PowerShell console windows* use UTF-8 consistently *when communication with external programs*<sup>[1]</sup>, both when sending data *to* external programs (`$OutputEncoding`) and when interpreting data *from* external programs (`[Console]::OutputEncoding`):

  - In short, place the following statement in your `$PROFILE`:

    ```bash
    $OutputEncoding = [Console]::InputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()
    ```
  - If you're running in the - [obsolescent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) - Windows PowerShell *ISE*, you need an additional command to ensure that the ISE first allocates a hidden console behind the scenes; note that in the recommended replacement, [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell), this is *not* necessary:

    ```bash
    $null = chcp # Run any console application to force the ISE to create a console.
    $OutputEncoding = [Console]::InputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()
    ```
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) for a *system-wide* way to make non-Unicode (console) applications use UTF-8, available in recent versions of Windows 10. This makes both `cmd.exe` and PowerShell use UTF-8 by default.<sup>[1]</sup>

  - Caveat: This feature is still in beta a of Windows 11 22H2, and it has *far-reaching consequences* - see the linked answer.

---

<sup>[1] What encoding *PowerShell's own cmdlets* use is *not* controlled by this; PowerShell cmdlets have their own defaults, which are - unfortunately - inconsistent in *Windows PowerShell*, whereas in PowerShell [Core] v6+ (BOM-less) UTF-8 is the consistent default; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098904/45375).</sup>

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0 thank you, it's working now I just pasted '[console]::InputEncoding = [console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()' in my $profile then close and open visual studio code, killed the terminal open again, run the program and it properly outputs now, don't know what was happening before, I didn't had to add $null = chcp on the $profile file. Accepting your answer, thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked, @TiagoM; my pleasure. Note that I do see the problem you were describing in the ISE if the statement is placed in its `$PROFILE`, but only if no console application was invoked first.