# Powershell script fails to run due to unicode character

Tags: powershell, unicode

I have a Powershell script that is failing due to unicode characters in it:

MyScript.ps1:

```
Write-Host "Installing 無書籤..."
```

When I run this script from Powershell command line, I get the following error:

[image]

I gather the issue is Powershell is running in ASCII or some other non-unicode mode. I tried changing it like this:

```
$OutputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.UTF8Encoding]::UTF8
```

But the error still persists. How do I get Powershell to run my script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The screen shot implies that you're using *Windows PowerShell*, which interprets *BOM-less*  `*.ps1` files as *ANSI*-encoded (using the usually single-byte ANSI code page determined by the legacy system locale); by contrast, *PowerShell [Core] v6+* now assumes UTF-8.

Therefore, for **Windows PowerShell** to correctly interpret CJK characters **you must save your `*.ps1` file using a *Unicode* encoding *with BOM***; given that PowerShell source code itself uses ASCII-range characters (resulting in a mix of Latin and CJK characters), the **best choice is UTF-8 *with BOM***.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `$OutputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.UTF8Encoding]::UTF8`

These settings only apply when PowerShell communicates with *external programs* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49481797/45375).

Answer (score 1):

First, write and save your script, which contains Unicode characters, in the Windows PowerShell ISE program
Then you can edit it with any program like visual code or ...
This method should be useful.