# How to use the character ⛁ (U+26C1) in Java?

Tags: java

for a study project I am using java to develop a game.
I need to fill the board (chess-like) with these characters "⛀", "⛁","⛂","⛃" (Unicode: "U+26C0","U+26C1 ","U+26C2","U+26C3").
I get the correct printing only if I use, to run the application, git Bash; otherwise, for example on Powershell, I get '?' or other random stuff.
To print I just use the line (for example): `System.out.print(" " + "\u26C2" + " ");`
How can I get the application to print the correct characters in every terminal I decide to run from?
Thanks.

Comment: Java can't help you with that. Use a character that you know works everywhere, or don't use a terminal at all.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49476326/15273968

Comment: "print the correct characters in every terminal I decide to run from": Set the terminal to support unicode. If the terminal not supports unicode then printing unicode characters will fail.

Comment: Different terminals have different unicode encodings and support different characters. Some terminals might support UTF-8 (Most characters) while others don't.