# Python - Get command output cannot be decoded

Tags: python, powershell, utf-8, decode

I'm currently working on a project where I need to run a command in powershell, and part of the output is not in English (Specifically - Hebrew).

For example (a simplified version of the problem), if I want to get the content of my desktop, and there is a filename in Hebrew:

```
import subprocess
command = "powershell.exe ls ~/Desktop"
print (subprocess.run(command.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode())
```

This code will raise the following error (Or something similar with a different byte value):

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 19: invalid start byte
```

Tried to run it on a different computer, and this was the output:

```
?????
```

Any idea why is that and how can I fix it? Tried a lot of things I saw on other questions, but none of them worked for me.

Comment: Try to use `decode()` with `encoding` parameter, for example `decode(encoding="latin1")`

Comment: Output character encoding is dependant on your system/os/shell settings. If you get the  UnicodeDecodeError, it means that the output captured is *NOT* unicode.  You might be able to fetch the encoding with `locale.getpreferredencoding()` and use that as parameter to `decode()` as @Marino pointed out above.

Comment: @Marino Latin-1 doesn't support Hebrew. Decoding will succeed (because *any* byte sequence can be decoded with Latin-1), but the result probably will be garbage.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Unfortunately - none of them worked :( The command output in python I think is literally the char `?`, not really sure why.

Comment: Can you give some example file names that you are having issues with?

Comment: `קובץראשון.txt` for example

Comment: `b'\x96'.decode('cp862')` returns `'צ'` (_Hebrew Letter Tsadi_). Please share raw bytes `print (subprocess.run(command.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: The following are **Python 3+ solutions**, but there is a **caveat**:

- With the ***first* solution below** and also with the second one - but *only if* UTF-8 data must be sent to PowerShell's *stdin* stream - due to **a bug in `powershell.exe`**, the [*Windows PowerShell* CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the **current console window *switches to a raster font*** (potentially with a different font size), which does *not* support most non-extended-ASCII-range Unicode characters. While visually jarring, **this is merely a *display* (rendering) problem**; the data is handled correctly; switching back to a Unicode-aware font such as `Consolas` reveals the correct output.
- By contrast, **`pwsh.exe`**, the [*PowerShell (Core)* (v6+) CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pwsh) **does *not* exhibit this problem**.

---

**Option A: Configure *both* the console *and* Python to use *UTF-8* character encoding *before* executing your script:**

- Configure the **console** to use UTF-8:

  - From `cmd.exe`, by switching the active OEM code page to `65001` (UTF-8); note that this change potentially affects all later calls to console applications in the session, independently of Python, unless you restore the original code page (see Option B below):

    ```
    chcp 65001
    ```
  - From PowerShell:

    ```
    $OutputEncoding = [Console]::InputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()
    ```
- *And* configure **Python** (v3+) to use UTF-8 *consistently*:<sup>[1]</sup>

  - Set environment variable `PYTHONUTF8` to `1`, possibly *persistently*, via the registry; to do it *ad hoc*:

    - From `cmd.exe`:

      ```
      Set PYTHONUTF8=1
      ```
    - From PowerShell:

      ```
      $env:PYTHONUTF8=1
      ```
  - Alternatively, for an individual call (v3.7+): Pass command-line option `-X utf8` to the `python` interpreter (note: case matters):

    ```
      python -X utf8 somefile.py ...
    ```
  - Both options enable **[Python UTF-8 Mode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#utf8-mode)**, which ***will become the default in Python 3.15***.

Now, your original code should work as-is (except for the display bug).

Note:

- A **simpler alternative via a one-time configuration step** is to configure your system to **use UTF-8 *system-wide***, in which case both the OEM and the ANSI code pages are set to `65001`. However, this has **far-reaching consequences** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375).

---

**Option B: (Temporarily) switch to UTF-8 for the PowerShell call:**

```py
import sys, ctypes, subprocess

# Switch Python's own encoding to UTF-8, if necessary
# This is the in-script equivalent of setting environment var. 
# PYTHONUTF8 to 1 *before* calling the script.
sys.stdin.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8'); sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8'); sys.stderr.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')

# Save the current console output code page and switch to 65001 (UTF-8)
previousCp = windll.kernel32.GetConsoleOutputCP()
windll.kernel32.SetConsoleOutputCP(65001)

# PowerShell now emits UTF-8-encoded output; decode it as such.
command = "powershell.exe ls ~/Desktop"
print(subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode())

# Restore the previous output console code page.
windll.kernel32.SetConsoleOutputCP(previousCp)
```

Note:

- Due to setting only the *output* console page, the **Windows PowerShell display bug is avoided**.
- If you also wanted to **send input to PowerShell's *stdin* stream**, you'd have to **set the *input* console page too**, via `windll.kernel32.SetConsoleCP(65001)` (which **would then again surface the display bug**).

---

<sup>[1] This isn't strictly necessary just for correctly decoding PowerShell's output, but matters if you want to pass that output *on* from Python: Python 3.x defaults to the active ANSI(!) code page for encoding *non-console* output, which means that Hebrew characters, for instance, cannot be represented in non-console output (e.g., when redirecting to a *file*), and cause the script to break.</sup>