# Powershell: What are question marks in square boxes?

Tags: powershell

When I input the `Get-LocalGroup` command in Windows PowerShell, the output is full of question marks in boxes under the *description* section.

The `Get-LocalUser` command had the same issue.

There are no error messages.

This is a Japanese machine, with English language package downloaded for Windows10. Has this caused the problem?

Comment: Probably an encoding issue. Maybe try setting Powershell's output format to UTF8: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49476326/displaying-unicode-in-powershell

Comment: @marsze 
Thank you, this did the trick. 

Unfortunately though when I change the font to *Mincho* (which can handle Japanese), it also changes backslashes to yen signs.

Comment: Have you tried a different font? Maybe `SimSun-ExtB` mentioned in the linked post.