# Working with resource IDs containing hash in Azure CLI

Tags: powershell, azure-cli

When inspecting certificate resources during a cleanup preparation, I came across several ones whose resource ID contains a hash character (`#`). When I tried getting their details, Azure CLI failed.

```
az resource show --subscription $subs --ids `
    $(az resource list --subscription $subs --resource-group $rg `
        --resource-type Microsoft.Web/certificates --query '[].id' --output tsv)
```

```
(MissingApiVersionParameter) The api-version query parameter (?api-version=) is required for all requests.
```

The inner command gives this list:

```
/subscriptions/deadbeef-2021-4b7b-988c-abcdabcdabcd/resourceGroups/testrg/prodivers/Microsoft.Web/certificates/018B8D7BEAEB68E5A074B61434030D42CD46E3E2##West Europe#
/subscriptions/deadbeef-2021-4b7b-988c-abcdabcdabcd/resourceGroups/testrg/providers/Microsoft.Web/certificates/2B1CA607A52CBDC62716009CF13DEDFA859B72D2#testrg-WestEuropewebspace
/subscriptions/deadbeef-2021-4b7b-988c-abcdabcdabcd/resourceGroups/testrg/providers/Microsoft.Web/certificates/59BB3E72F7281D7FCACF7B8A8DDB3D23FE0BF09E##West Europe#
/subscriptions/deadbeef-2021-4b7b-988c-abcdabcdabcd/resourceGroups/testrg/providers/Microsoft.Web/certificates/81295C08FF441A0CA954B04E58A06991472468E1##West Europe#
/subscriptions/deadbeef-2021-4b7b-988c-abcdabcdabcd/resourceGroups/testrg/providers/Microsoft.Web/certificates/B9E64EDE44DC848B39CC6872BD310B6BEF070FC9-testrg-WestEuropewebspace
/subscriptions/deadbeef-2021-4b7b-988c-abcdabcdabcd/resourceGroups/testrg/providers/Microsoft.Web/certificates/some.domain.cz-003090D185A4A57C83E4F1E664EB12C7143D5CB1
/subscriptions/deadbeef-2021-4b7b-988c-abcdabcdabcd/resourceGroups/testrg/providers/Microsoft.Web/certificates/F660F6675F0943D93F2780A9F65B48147A375913-testrg-WestEuropewebspace
/subscriptions/deadbeef-2021-4b7b-988c-abcdabcdabcd/resourceGroups/testrg/providers/Microsoft.Web/certificates/some-test.domain.com-1B856146B6287E8D0D68C98E9A66B7D23A969762
/subscriptions/deadbeef-2021-4b7b-988c-abcdabcdabcd/resourceGroups/testrg/providers/Microsoft.Web/certificates/some-test.domain.com-B2FBC6E5DD564B6762FF34EA1A8C1C432A2B7510
```

When using the outer command separately on each one, the ones without a hash pass (details are printed) and the ones with the hash fail with the aforementioned error.

```
$p = '/subscriptions/deadbeef-2021-4b7b-988c-abcdabcdabcd/resourceGroups/testrg/providers/Microsoft.Web/certificates'
az resource show --subscription $subs --ids `
    "$p/018B8D7BEAEB68E5A074B61434030D42CD46E3E2##West Europe#"
```

**Is it a bug of Azure CLI?** I am using Azure CLI 2.27.2, which is the current stable version. **Or are those some arcane deprecated resources that need some special treatment? How to work with them?**

Comment: Don't know if it is relevant, but I suspect some of the certificates have been uploaded manually through Azure Portal and some have been created by the Let's Encrypt site extension for Azure App Service. https://github.com/sjkp/letsencrypt-siteextension

Comment: I found that using Azure CLI from PowerShell scripts is quite a bad idea and Azure PS should be used instead. Recently, a colleague created a resource whose name contains Unicode characters. It breaks my scripts on Windows because Windows has lousy Unicode support. I have found no way to fix them. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49481797/2157640 https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/14426

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By trial and error I found that escaping is the issue. When I URL-encode each component of the resource ID, it works. Seems like a bug after all.

```
az resource show --subscription $subs --ids `
    "$p/018B8D7BEAEB68E5A074B61434030D42CD46E3E2%23%23West%20Europe%23"
```

```
az resource show --subscription $subs --ids `
    $(az resource list --subscription $subs --resource-group $rg `
        --resource-type Microsoft.Web/certificates --query '[].id' --output tsv |
        ForEach-Object { `
            [string]::Join('/', ($_ -split '/' |
                ForEach-Object { [uri]::EscapeDataString($_) })) `
        })
```

Comment: A somewhat related issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/12885

Comment: Sometimes when a special character is at the end of the ID (e.g. a scheduled query rule `Web App Exception (500)`), it helps when a space is added at the end of the ID. I believe this is hacking some issues with passing parameters from PowerShell to external commands.