# UTF-8 and CJK doesn't displaying with gets in Ruby (Windows)

Tags: ruby, windows, powershell, utf-8, cjk

I recently started to use Vim, but I'm having some encoding problems, and I'm not really sure if it's a Ruby problem or a cmd/powershell problem, but Ruby is not accepting CJK characters with `gets`, and sometimes printing isn't working properly.

**gets error**
The following images are from cmd and powershell, it shows how `p`, `puts` and `print` print it (I don't know if it is important tho), and the code is just `var = gets`

[image: cmd]

[image: powershell]

**printing "error"**
In powershell, `p` printing doesn't work if I use CJK (apparently it doesn't work with UTF-8), but in cmd all works perfectly
[image: powershell]

**What I already tried:**

*Set cmd and powershell encoding as UTF-8*: In cmd it worked, but in powershell I don't seems to work. I tried `$PSDefaultParameterValues['Out-File:Encoding'] = 'utf8'` and `$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:Encoding'] = 'utf8'` as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40098771/changing-powershells-default-output-encoding-to-utf-8) answer

*Changing cmd and powershell font*: As you can see in the images, the font supports CJK (MS Mincho)

*Open cmd with UTF-8*: I'm using `cmd /K chcp 65001` to open cmd

**Other informations:**

Windows 10

```rb
irb(main):001:0> RUBY_VERSION
=> "2.7.3"
```

```rb
irb(main):001:0> Encoding.default_external
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

Comment: The answer you link to is focused on making PowerShell cmdlets _output_ UTF-8 (I've updated it  to make that clearer). The more relevant answer may be [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49481797/45375).