# Dhall Repl: strange formatting issues (Powershell on Windows 10 64bit)

Tags: powershell, read-eval-print-loop, dhall

When I'm working with `dhall repl` in Powershell I get a lot of weird output / encoding issues.
I'm using the precompiled binaries for windows from https://github.com/dhall-lang/dhall-haskell/releases.

An example:

```
Welcome to the Dhall v1.40.1 REPL! Type :help for more information.
|- let makeSnippet = ./makeSnippet.dhall in makeSnippet "" []

Ôå│ ./makeSnippet.dhall
  Ôå│ ./Snippet.dhall

Error: Invalid type for ÔØ░ListÔØ▒

2Ôöé          [Text]

C:\xxx\Snippet.dhall:2:10

1Ôöé               ./Snippet.dhall

C:\xxx\makeSnippet.dhall:1:15
|- let makeSnippet = ./makeSnippet.dhall in makeSnippet "test" [ "test" ]

Ôå│ ./makeSnippet.dhall
  Ôå│ ./Snippet.dhall
```

I have this problem in `dhall repl` and in `dhall repl --ascii` as well.
When running the Repl in `Git Bash` it works:

```
(input):2:1:
  |
2 | <empty line>
  | ^
unexpected end of input
expecting #!, expression, or whitespace

⊢ :let greeting = "hello"

greeting : Text

⊢ ./makeSnippet.dhall

↳ ./makeSnippet.dhall
  ↳ ./Snippet.dhall

Error: Invalid type for ❰List❱
```

I was really surprised to see that error diagnostics in `--ascii` invocation of the repl seem to use unicode characters as well - is that on purpose?

What i tried so far (without success):

- Changing the font to Lucidca
- Changing the font to `DejaVu Sans Mono`
- Changing the codepage via `chcp 65001`

I would really like to use dhall with powershell. So any ideas how to solve this issues are highly welcome!

Many thanks in advance!

Julian

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying Unicode in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49476326/displaying-unicode-in-powershell)

Comment: Also, it is a bug that the error diagnostics don't respect the --ascii flag.  If you open an issue I will try to address this

Answer (score 2):

This helped:

[Displaying Unicode in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49476326/displaying-unicode-in-powershell)

I had to enter

```
$OutputEncoding = [console]::InputEncoding = [console]::OutputEncoding = 
New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding
```