# Why is \v not adding vertical tab in lua 5.3.6?

Tags: powershell, terminal, lua

```
print('hello\vworld')
```

Does not print as intended. ♂ is printed instead of the vertical tab, i.e., `hello♂world` Here's an image of the output in the terminal.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Lua is printing an ASCII or UTF-8 vertical tab - `0x0B` hex, 11 decimal - as requested, but your PowerShell is set to a different encoding ("code page"). It's probably "DOS Latin 1" (850), "DOS Latin US" (437) or similar. On these code pages, `0x0B` represents the Mars symbol.

The `chcp` command shows which code page is active. You can use the "magic incantation" from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49481797/182402) to change the code page of your PowerShell to UTF-8.

Comment: i did change my powershell encoding to UTF-8 but still the output is the same. Any idea why?