# Trim powershell output after a specific line

Tags: string, powershell

When running the sfc /scannow command from a powershell script, how do you trim the output to only keep all the data after "Verification 100% complete."?

Simple code example:

```
 $Result = Invoke-Command { sfc /scannow } | Out-String
```

A truncated version of this output is:

```
Verification 97% complete. 
Verification 98% complete.
Verification 98% complete.
Verification 99% complete.
Verification 99% complete.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files and successfully repaired them.

For online repairs, details are included in the CBS log file located at

windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For example C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For offline

repairs, details are included in the log file provided by the /OFFLOGFILE flag.
```

I also wouldn't mind removing the extraneous line breaks so the final output when returning $Result would simply be:

> Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files and successfully repaired them. For online repairs, details are included in the CBS log file located at windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For example C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For offline repairs, details are included in the log file provided by the /OFFLOGFILE flag.

I have a 1024 character limit for the output, and right now I'm just truncating it with the following:

```
if ($Result.length -gt 1024) {
        $Result = $Result.Substring($Result.Length-1024)
    }
```

But I'd like to get rid of all the "status" type messaging from the output and just retain the final result of the scan.

Thank you!

Comment: What did you try to filter? Did you read the manual https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string?view=powershell-7.2 ? (It includes an example that might help)

Comment: ```$result = (sfc /scannow) -replace "`0" |  where-object  {$_ -and $_ -notmatch 'Verification'}``` think this helps

Comment: Thanks, this code worked perfectly. Can you help me understand what the `0 represents? My google skills apparently suck on this and I can't find an answer.

Comment: @sk8erord `0 represents null characters. A full list is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost this is an **encoding** issue. The `sfc` command outputs UTF-16, but PowerShell doesn't know that (because it's a *native* command), so you typically get embedded *null* characters between the actual characters (try `sfc /? | Out-String | Format-Hex` to see what I mean).

Removing the embedded *null* characters would only *partially* fix the symptoms. On non-english systems the encoding of non-ASCII characters will still be wrong.

To fix the cause, you have to tell PowerShell the **output encoding** used by the command (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49481797/7571258) for background, albeit it focuses on UTF-8):

```sh
# Save the current encoding settings and temporarily switch to UTF-16 (aka UnicodeEncoding).
$oldOutputEncoding = $OutputEncoding; $oldConsoleEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding
$OutputEncoding = [console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UnicodeEncoding

# No need for Invoke-Command. Just call it directly.
$result = sfc /scannow | Out-String

# Restore the previous settings.
$OutputEncoding = $oldOutputEncoding; [Console]::OutputEncoding = $oldConsoleEncoding

# Encoding fixed, but duplicate newlines remain. Replace them by single newlines:
$result = $result -replace '\r?\n\r?\n', [Environment]::NewLine

#Finally strip off everything up to and including the `100%` line:
$result = ($result -replace '(?s)^.*100\s*%.*?\r?\n').Trim()
```

See this [RegEx101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/DnTJX8/3) for an explanation of the RegEx used by the last `-replace` command. Note that `(?s)` enables *single-line mode* so dot `.` matches newlines.