# Add copyright character into json file from PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, encoding, symbols

I have a script that updates a configuration file with current year, but for some reason the copyright symbol is not being inserted correctly. The PowerShell script is UTF-8 with BOM and the JSON file is UTF-8.

The workflow is that I read from a JSON file, update the copyright date, and then save to a JSON file again.

The JSON file `info.json`:

```
{
    "CopyrightInfo":  "Copyright © CompanyName 1992"
}
```

Reproducible excerpt of the PowerShell script:

```
$path = "./info.json"
$a = Get-Content $path| ConvertFrom-Json
$a.'CopyrightInfo' = "Copyright $([char]::ConvertFromUtf32(0x000000A9)) CompanyName $((Get-Date).Year)"
$a | ConvertTo-Json | set-content $path
```

I've tried a bunch of ways, above is the latest attempt. It looks fine when printed in PowerShell or opened in Notepad, but any other editor (Visual Studio Code, SourceTree, Azure DevOps file viewer, etc) they always result in the following:

```
"CopyrightInfo":  "Copyright � CompanyName 2022"
```

If anyone can explain what I'm doing wrong that would great and even greater if they could also add a way to make it work properly.

I'm using PowerShell version 5.1.19041.1682

EDIT: Updated issue with reproducible code excerpts and used PowerShell version.

Comment: @iRon Good point. I have updated the question now with reproducible example and powershell version.

Comment: As an aside: `$([char] 0xA9)` should do to create the `©` sign. In PowerShell (Core), you can simplify to ``"`u{A9}"``

Comment: Are you sure the script isn't utf8 no bom encoding?  Powershell 5.1 doesn't like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you're running ***Windows PowerShell*** and that you want to both read the input and create the output as *UTF-8*-encoded:

- If it's acceptable to create a **UTF-8 file *with BOM*** (which is what `Set-Content -Encoding utf8` in Windows PowerShell invariably creates):

  ```
  # Note the use of -Encoding utf8 in both statements.
  # (In PowerShell (Core) 7+, neither would be needed,
  # and Set-Content would create a BOM-*less* UTF-8 file;
  # you'd need -Encoding utf8BOM to create one *with* a BOM).

  $a = Get-Content -Encoding utf8 $path| ConvertFrom-Json
  # ...
  $a | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 $path
  ```
- Creating a **UTF-8 file *without BOM*** requires more work in *Windows PowerShell*, whereas it is **now the *consistent default* in [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)**, taking advantage of the - curious - fact that [`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item), when given a `-Value` argument, (invariably) creates files with that encoding:

  ```
  # (In PowerShell (Core) 7+, -Encoding utf8 wouldn't be needed,
  # and Set-Content would create a BOM-*less* UTF-8 file by default.)

  $a = Get-Content -Encoding utf8 $path| ConvertFrom-Json
  # ...
  New-Item -Force -Path $path -Value (($a | ConvertTo-Json) + "`r`n")
  ```

---

Note:

- On **reading**: PowerShell recognizes Unicode BOMs automatically, but **what encoding is *assumed* in the *absence* of a BOM** depends on the PowerShell edition, both when reading source code and when reading files via cmdlets, such as via [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content):

  - **Windows PowerShell** assumes the system's legacy **ANSI** code page (aka language for non-Unicode programs).
  - **PowerShell (Core)** assumes **UTF-8**.
- On **writing**: Once a file is read, **PowerShell does *not* preserve information about an input file's original character encoding** - the file content is stored in .NET strings (which are composed of in-memory UTF-16LE code units), even when the data is simply passed through the pipeline. As such, **it is a file-writing cmdlet's own *default* encoding that is used** if no `-Encoding` argument is specified, irrespective of where the data came from; specifically:

  - **Windows PowerShell's [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-5.1)** defaults to the system legacy **ANSI** encoding; unfortunately, **other cmdlets have *different* defaults**; notably, **`Out-File`** and its virtual alias, **`>`**, default to **UTF-16LE ("Unicode")** - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098904/45375) for details.
  - **PowerShell (Core)** now fortunately defaults to **BOM-less UTF-8, across *all* cmdlets**.

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce the issue:

```
$Data = @{ CopyrightInfo = "Copyright $([char]::ConvertFromUtf32(0x000000A9)) CompanyName $((Get-Date).Year)" }
$Json = ConvertTo-Json $Data
$Json |Set-Content .\Test.json
$Json = Get-Content -Raw .\Test.json
$Data = ConvertFrom-Json $Json
$Data
```

```
CopyrightInfo
-------------
Copyright © CompanyName 2022
```

To show the result in PowerShell with any external program see: [Displaying Unicode in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49481797/1701026)

```
$OutputEncoding = [console]::InputEncoding = [console]::OutputEncoding =  New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding
```

Comment: I apologise. I've updated my example to make a bit clearer. It displays it as intended in PowerShell, but when I view the file with anything else the symbol is replaced.

Comment: I mentioned it in the example, but Visual Studio Code, the file viewer in SourceTree, and the file viewer in Azure DevOps. The command returns utf-8.

Comment: Ah, seems the issue was that PowerShell wasn't setting the correct encoding somehow. Adding explicit parameters (`Set-Content -Encoding "utf8" -Path $path`) did the trick.