# PowerShell Copy-Item: how to copy only folder contents if source path requires -literalPath

Tags: powershell

As part of a larger script, I'm trying to get PowerShell to copy the contents of a specified folder into another directory. The problem I'm having is that I need to use `-LiteralPath` as this script will ultimately be used to copy the contents of various folders, many of which include the problematic EmDash. As such, my code at the moment looks something like this:

```
Copy-Item -LiteralPath "C:\Example – Path\SourcePath" -Destination "C:\DestinationPath" -Recurse -Force
```

However, using `-LiteralPath` prevents me  from being able to append wildcards to the path. So I can't just have

```
C:\Example – Path\SourcePath\*
```

to specify that I only want the contents of the source folder copied, rather than the entire directory.

Being a rookie with creating scripts, I've been relying on Chat-GPT for assistance and it has provided an alternative solution where I define a custom function that performs the copy procedure as needed. But I'm just wondering if there's something cleaner / simpler which will obviate the need for a new function.

Any thoughts or suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: En dash.  `copy 'Example – Path\*' DestinationPath` works for me.

Comment: Try XCOPY which will work with PS.  It is a cmd.exe method. Open cmd.exe and type >Help XCOPY

Comment: Note that a powershell 5.1 script has to be utf8 *with bom*.

Comment: @js2010, I'm aware of this option and would love to be able to use this solution but unfortunately in this case it's not viable for me to replace all directories containing an EmDash with an EnDash. Not only are there too many, but new folders get periodically imported from outside my computer and I can't control what naming convention they use.

But I do acknowledge that your answer is absolutely valid in the context of the parameters I outlined in the original post.

Re: encoding, indeed, I already ran into problems on account of this. Fortunately all resolved now.

Comment: @jdweng, this sounds promising. I've used XCOPY in batch files to perform similar operations. I didn't know it was an option in PowerShell. This seems like the most promising avenue for a solution.

Comment: emdash or endash doesn't matter.  I'm just saying your question has an endash.

Comment: @js2010, is `copy` an altogether different function to `Copy-Item`? Because when troubleshooting this initially, it was 100% the dash that was causing the problem. As soon as I removed it from the path, everything worked perfectly.

Comment: copy and copy-item are the same thing

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what the difference is. Just confirmed with further tests using a simple `Get-ChildItem` on a directory path with a ' – '. It fails to find the contents every time. As soon as I change the name to remove the dash, it works perfectly.

`-literalPath` overcomes this problem but at the cost of removing the option to add wildcards.

Comment: @jdweng: "It is a cmd.exe method" is misleading: `xcopy.exe` is an _executable file_ that ships with Windows,  just like `cmd.exe`, the default shell, and `powershell.exe`, _Windows PowerShell_. As such, it exists _independently_ of the latter two, and can therefore be called from _any_ process, including these two shells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The purpose of the **`-LiteralPath`** parameter of PowerShell cmdlets is to interpret its argument(s) ***literally*, a.k.a *verbatim***.
- By contrast, the purpose of the **`-Path`** parameter is to interpret its argument(s) as **[*wildcard*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) patterns**, such as `'C:\Example – Path\SourcePath\*'`

Therefore, use `-Path`, not `-LiteralPath`:

```bash
Copy-Item -Path "C:\Example – Path\SourcePath\*" -Destination "C:\DestinationPath" -Recurse -Force
```

**Note**:

- In PowerShell [provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Providers) cmdlets such as [`Copy-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item), **`-Path` is the (first) *positional* parameter, so that you may *omit* `-Path`** in the command above.

  - Conversely, this means: **In order to ensure that file path argument(s) are interpreted *literally* (*verbatim*)**, you *must* **use `-LiteralPath`** or, in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) its **`-lp` *alias***.
  - While **the distinction between `-Path` and `-LiteralPath` *typically* doesn't matter**, it ***does* with paths that happen to contain `[` and `]`**, as these characters are *metacharacters* in PowerShell wildcard patterns.
- **Your specific path contains a *non-ASCII-range* character**, `–` (EN DASH, [`U+2013`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013)), which *looks like*, but *isn't the same as* the *ASCII-range* `-` character (HYPHEN-MINUS, [`U+002D`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2d))

  - As long as PowerShell interprets your script file correctly, that isn't a problem.
  - However, if your script file is UTF-8 encoded, but *lacks a BOM* (byte-order mark), *Windows PowerShell* will misinterpret it.

    - To **ensure safe *cross-edition* use of PowerShell scripts, be sure to save them as UTF-8 *with BOM*** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74389785/45375).