# how to see language other than English (ex Korean) in windows powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell

I see this in powershell.

[image]

strange!

but when paste it

```
사용법: wsl.exe [인수]

인수:

    --install <옵션>
        Linux용 Windows 하위 시스템 기능을 설치합니다. 옵션을 지정하지 않으면
        권장 기능은 기본 배포와 함께 설치됩니다.

        기본 배포 및 다른 유효한 배포 목록을 보려면
        'wsl --list --online'을 사용하세요.

        옵션:
            --distribution, -d [인수]
               이름별로 다운로드 및 설치할 배포를 지정합니다.

                인수:
                    유효한 배포 이름(대소문자 구분 안 함).

                예:
                    wsl --install -d Ubuntu
                    wsl --install --distribution Debian

    --list, -l [옵션]
        배포를 나열합니다.

        옵션:
            --online, -o
                'wsl --install'로 설치할 수 있는 배포 목록을 표시합니다.

    --help
        사용 정보를 표시합니다.
```

this is correct.

How to i escape to '?'

As far as I know 'UTF-8' is the key to this problem, it doesn't work the way i want.

C:\Users????\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
content of this is
$env:LC_ALL='C.UTF-8'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying Unicode in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49476326/displaying-unicode-in-powershell)

Comment: Your encoding is fine; you need a CJK-friendly font.