# How do I get UTF-8 to work flawlessly in modern PowerShell on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, powershell, encoding, utf-8

I have a C++ program which outputs raw UTF-8 and works flawlessly on Linux, but on Windows shells the output is not as nice. "®" turns into "┬«", "©" turns into "┬⌐", for example.
There is also a Python part to the code, which seems to work better when printing to the shell, so I tried to test Python output a bit.

```
PS C:\Users\user> python -c 'print("\N{GREEK CAPITAL LETTER DELTA}")' > test_file_python.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0394' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
PS C:\Users\user> python -X utf8 -c 'print("\N{GREEK CAPITAL LETTER DELTA}")' > test_file_python.txt
PS C:\Users\user> cat test_file_python.txt
╬ö
PS C:\Users\user> python -c 'print("\N{GREEK CAPITAL LETTER DELTA}")'
Δ
PS C:\Users\user> cat .\test_file_python_wsl.txt  # Generated in WSL with the above commands
Δ
PS C:\Users\user> Format-Hex .\test_file_python.txt

   Label: C:\Users\user\test_file_python.txt

          Offset Bytes                                           Ascii
                 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
          ------ ----------------------------------------------- -----
0000000000000000 E2 95 AC C3 B6 0D 0A                            â�¬Ã¶��

PS C:\Users\user> Format-Hex .\test_file_python_wsl.txt

   Label: C:\Users\user\test_file_python_wsl.txt

          Offset Bytes                                           Ascii
                 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
          ------ ----------------------------------------------- -----
0000000000000000 CE 94 0A                                        Î��
```

I do not understand how PowerShell works with encoding, how can Python do this right when writing to the shell but not when redirecting, and why something that works perfectly in Linux Bash in WSL has this sort of issues in the newer cross-platform PowerShell Core which should "just work".
These are multiple questions, but probably have a common answer.

EDIT:
I forgot to add some important information, I am using PowerShell Core v7.3.6 with this encoding settings:

```
PS C:\Users\user> $OutputEncoding

Preamble          :
BodyName          : utf-8
EncodingName      : Unicode (UTF-8)
HeaderName        : utf-8
WebName           : utf-8
WindowsCodePage   : 1200
IsBrowserDisplay  : True
IsBrowserSave     : True
IsMailNewsDisplay : True
IsMailNewsSave    : True
IsSingleByte      : False
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.EncoderReplacementFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback
IsReadOnly        : True
CodePage          : 65001
```

Comment: The error message suggests that your console is configured to use code page 1252. Try `chcp 65001` but what works also depends on your Windows version. This is almost certainly a duplicate.

Comment: Have you tried using the -encoding utf8 in your cat statement?

Comment: I updated the post with more info, encoding settings already seem fine.

Comment: @tripleee, actually it is Python doing its own thing and using the _ANSI_ code page (e.g., Windows-1252) instead of the _OEM_ code page (e.g. CP 437) that console applications are expected to use. `chcp 1252` would help in principle, but not _from inside PowerShell_, due to .NET's _caching_ of encodings in its `[Console]` class, which PowerShell uses to decode output from child processes. Using the ANSI code page can still break depending on the characters in the Python output, so UTF-8 is the only robust solution, which - unfortunately - requires extra effort in _both_ Python and PowerShell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows, there are two pieces to the puzzle:

- You must **instruct *PowerShell* to use UTF-8** when communicating with external programs.

  - Use the following magic incantation (note that `chcp 65001`, which is what you'd do from `cmd.exe`, is *not* an option, because .NET *caches* the encodings stored in `[Console]`):

    ```
     $OutputEncoding = [Console]::InputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding
    ```
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49481797/45375) for background information.
- You must **instruct *Python* to use UTF-8 I/O too** (assumes Python v3.7+):

  - Either: Pass `-X utf8` (case matters) to the `python` executable:

    ```
    python -X utf8 -c 'print("\N{GREEK CAPITAL LETTER DELTA}")' > test_file_python.txt
    ```
  - Or: Before calling Python, run `$env:PYTHONUTF8=1`
  - The above enables **[Python UTF-8 Mode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#utf8-mode)**, which **will become the default in Python 3.15**.

---

An **alternative** via a one-time configuration step is to **switch your machine to use UTF-8 *system-wide***, in which case the above steps aren't necessary; however, **this has *far-reaching consequences* and can break legacy scripts and applications** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375).

---

##### Background information:

***PowerShell* is *partly* a good Windows console citizen:**

- It uses the encoding implied by the console window's active code pages (there's one for input, and one for output), which default to the system's legacy OEM code page; specifically:

  - When *decoding output* from an external program, it uses the console's output code page, as reflected in .NET in `[Console]::OutputEncoding`, which is what external programs are at least historically expected to use when encoding their output.
  - When *encoding input* to provide to external programs via the pipeline (the target program's stdin stream), PowerShell makes a strange choice, however; instead of using the console's active (input) code page, it uses the encoding stored in the [`$OutputEncoding` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#outputencoding), which has unexpected defaults:

    - In *Windows PowerShell* (the legacy, Windows-only, ships-with-Windows edition whose latest and *last* version is v5.1), it defaults to ASCII(!)
    - In [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) (the modern, cross-platform, install-on-demand edition) it defaults to UTF-8(!).

      - Note: PowerShell 7+ *internally* uses (BOM-less) UTF-8 consistently when *reading files*, including source code, and *writing to files*, but - of necessity - decoding output from *external programs* must still be based on the console's (output) code page.
      - [GitHub issue #7233](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7233) suggests making at least interactive PowerShell sessions also default to UTF-8 with respect to *external programs*, by setting the console code pages to `65001`.

***Python* exhibits *nonstandard* behavior:**

- When it finds its stdout stream *redirected*, it uses the system's legacy *ANSI*(!) code page for encoding its output by default.
- When *printing directly to the console*, problems that would result from misinterpretation when the output is captured or redirected do *not* surface, because Python then uses the relevant *Unicode* WinAPI to print to the console, bypassing any encoding issues:

  - In other words: Python's output always *displays* correctly when output *directly*, but misinterpretation can occur when *redirecting output to a file*, passing it on through *PowerShell's pipeline*, or capturing it in a *PowerShell variable*.

Comment: Thanks, I thought `$OutputEncoding` was enough, adding `[Console]::OutputEncoding` and `[Console]::InputEncoding` seems to give the right result, if `python -X utf8` is used. My understanding was that the new PowerShell Core would be using UTF-8 by default, but it does not seem so. Setting the encoding this way seems to fix the raw output from the C++ program as well.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @cubanpit. PowerShell Core _internally_ uses UTF-8, namely when reading files, including source code and when writing to files, but - of necessity - decoding output from _external programs_ must still be based on the console's (output) code page. Please see my update, which also points to a GitHub issues that suggests making interactive sessions use UTF-8 also with external programs.

Comment: Thanks for the background information and the link to the GitHub issue, it is all valuable material.