# Swing use different font for character which cannot display

Tags: java, swing, unicode, fonts

I am developping a text editor with Java swing, I want to use a monospace font to display (for example `Consolas` font):

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("text");
textArea.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.PLAIN, 12));
```

But if there's any unicode character(for ex: Japanese character), it shows square (this font does not support this kind of character).

I still want to use Consolas, but if there's any character which is not supported, it will use other font to render (a unicode font). How can I do that?

I think about use html to set font for each character but maybe it's too heavy. I just want 2 font: 1 monospace font & 1 unicode font

Comment: I would first try to find a Monospace font that supports unicode better. Maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938639/monospace-unicode-font?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @user3237736 I am thinking about create my own font by importing from other font, but maybe a programming solution is my expectation

Comment: @yelliver [1] My answer to an unrelated question on Japanese fonts  [_"String.format for double-width characters"_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53934253/2985643) might be helpful, though it wasn't about Swing. [2] As mentioned in that answer, try [Google's web site for fonts](https://fonts.google.com/) to search for monospaced Japanese fonts. [3] Have you tried using the **Monospaced** font instead of **Consolas**? I think it should render all Japanese characters. [4] If you find a monospace font that supports all Japanese characters, would you still need a "backup" Unicode font as well?