# Ruby on Windows displaying wrong unicode character in cmd terminal

Tags: ruby, windows, shell, unicode, cmd

Title pretty much sums it up.
I'm trying to display the chess unicode characters in the win10 command prompt and it displays the replacement character (�) instead (copy pasting that gives me the correct character again)

Enforcing UTF-8 encoding.
Setting the CMD Charpage to UTF-8 encoding.
Using the unicode characters instead of codes in my strings.

```
$icons = {
  "Pawn" => "\u2659", # ♙
  "Rook" => "\u2656", # ♖
  "Knight" => "\u2658", # ♘
  "Bishop" => "\u2657", # ♗
  "Queen" => "\u2655", # ♕
  "King" => "\u2654", # ♔

  "Black" => "\u25A0", # ■
  "White" => " " #
}

class Graphics
  def display_board(b);
  system ("cls")
  #system ("chcp 65001")
  board = b.get_map();
    board.each_with_index do |subarr,x|
      str = "";

      subarr.each_with_index do |value,y|
        str += "[" + $icons[value] + "]";
      end

      puts(str);
    end
  end
end
```

Expected result is this :

```
[♖][♘][♗][♔][♕][♗][♘][♖]
[♙][♙][♙][♙][♙][♙][♙][♙]
[ ][■][ ][■][ ][■][ ][■]
[■][ ][■][ ][■][ ][■][ ]
[ ][■][ ][■][ ][■][ ][■]
[■][ ][■][ ][■][ ][■][ ]
[♙][♙][♙][♙][♙][♙][♙][♙]
[♖][♘][♗][♔][♕][♗][♘][♖]
```

Actual result : 
� for every chess piece.

Comment: What codeset is your terminal using? A mismatch in the terminal will result in characters like that in the output. I get reasonable output in a Mac OS terminal set for UTF-8: `=> {"Pawn"=>"♙", "Rook"=>"♖", "Knight"=>"♘", "Bishop"=>"♗", "Queen"=>"♕", "King"=>"♔", "Black"=>"■", "White"=>" "}`

Comment: See my updated answer.  You need a font on windows which supports a broader set of UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't appear to be a ruby problem but rather the default encoding setting for windows and which fonts are used by the command prompt `cmd.exe`.

Here's how you should be able to get this to work.

1. Download and install [this free monospaced font](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/dejavu-sans-mono).
2. right click windows start button and select `Run` then type `regedit` and enter
3. type in the following path `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Console\TrueTypeFont`
4. Right click on the white area under the key entries and select `new > string value`
5. in the value data box type `Droid Sans Mono`
6. Click OK and then restart Windows.
7. Right click windows button > run > `cmd`
8. Right click the top of the window and select DejaVue Sans Mono font
9. Test it by typing this `ruby -e 'puts "\u2658"'`

You should see a font that outputs a knight ♘

For more help see https://www.thewindowsclub.com/add-custom-fonts-to-command-prompt

For other possible fonts which can be used see suggestions on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938639/monospace-unicode-font)